# unrar archive then rename the resulting files

Tags: rename, rar

My goal is to unrar and rename the resulting files.

test.rar contains

```
Oldname.txt
Oldname2.txt
...   - ...
```

Output after extracting should be:

```
Newname.txt
Newname2.txt
...   - ...
```

i make this code but it rename the rar file instead of the extracted files

```
for f in *.rar
do
unrar x $f;
mv -- "$f" "$(tr '[a-z][A-Z]' '[n-za-m][N-ZA-M]' <<< "$f")" ; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for renaming only 'rar' file is that

'$f' is item of '*.rar' collection in the loop, so only that gets renamed.

```
for f in *.rar
```

You need to execute a separate loop to iterate the extracted files and then rename them.